# Onchange dropdown set max value dynamically yii CMultiFileUpload

Tags: php, jquery, yii

```
 <?php
   echo $form->dropDownList($model,'ment_id', $mentslists,
        array(
        'prompt'=>'Select ment',
        'class'=>'required'
     ));
     echo $form->error($model,'ment_id'); 
     ?>
```

Onchange dropdownlist i want to set max value for the CMultiFileUpload.

my CMultiFileUpload code is ,

```
     <?php
$this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
           'name' => 'data1',
           'attribute' => 'image',
           'accept' => 'doc|docx|pdf|txt|jpeg|jpg|png',
            'max' => 10,
            'duplicate' => 'file appears twice',
            'remove' => Yii::t('ui', 'Remove'),
          ));
        ?>
```

i tried onchange dropdown get max allowed size value from database , how to apply the value to **max** field.

my jquery code is ,

```
$("#ment_id").on('change',function()
      {
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/ments/default/GetmentDetails",
     data: {'ment_id':$(this).val()},
     success: function(data){
         //data having the max upload value               
       }
     });
      });
```

my controller code is ,

```
public function actionGetmentDetails()
    {
        $id = $_POST['ment_id'];
        $assign_details = Ments::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('id'=>$id));
        echo $assign_details[0]['c_max_upload_files'];
        exit;
    }
```

how to set the **max** value dynamically based on changing dropdown list ,

Comment: Do you have a website that this is running on to take a look?

Answer (score 0):

It is a little vague on which point you got stuck, here is a back and forward in javacript/jquery.

```
$("#ment_id").on('change',function(){

  // Get max value before the ajax call 
  var maxValue = undefined;
  $('option', $(this)).each(function() {
        var val = $(this).attr('value');
        val = parseInt(val, 10);
        if (maxValue === undefined || maxValue < val) {
            maxValue = val;
        }
    });

 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/ments/default/GetmentDetails",
     data: {'ment_id':$(this).val()},
     success: function(data){
         //setting the retrieved max value by ajax response value  
         $("#ment_id").val(data.max_value); 
       }
     });
});
```

If you want that posted value in php and get passed to that widget code, it is more of a question where that widget method is called, since you have the value as a $_POST in place already.